# Understanding the E step of EM for GMM

Tags: probability, self-study, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I'm reading this chapter about EM (9.3.1) of the book "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning".

I understand the basic EM algorithm for GMM, but I'm having some problems understanding the probabilistic interpretation of the E step.

Most of the following formulas make sense to me except 9.39. Can someone please explain it for me? Thanks a lot.

It seems that it is in the form of $$E[z_{nk}]=\frac{\sum_{z_{nk}}z_{nk}f(n,k)}{normalizer}$$ 
where the numerator is a summation over two possible states of $z_{nk}$ (0 and 1), so it becomes $\pi_kN(x_n|\mu_k,\Sigma_k)$ in the second step, am I right so far?

If so, what are we summing over here in the denominator? 0s and 1s of all possible $j$s (but the result doesn't quite match)? Why $f(n,k)=[\pi_kN(x_n|\mu_k,\Sigma_k)]^{z_{nk}}$ is used as an unnormalized probability?

**It would make more sense if the denominator is the unnormalized zeroth moment and the numerator is the unnormalized first moment, did I understand it correctly?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator is the summation over a $K$-dimensional one-hot vector, so the indicator variable only equal $z_{nk}$ to 1 once.

The denominator is the unnormalized zeroth moment, and can be shown to be equal to the summation over $K$ summations of such $K$-dimensional vectors.

See this question for more details [Derivation of expectation-maximization in General - PRML](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/226404/95569)